# What is wrong with my code here in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I am following a tutorial online for tkinter and this was one of the lines of code:

```
button1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
```

This is the error that it gives me when I run this:

```
invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 18)
```

What do I need to fix?

Here is all of the code that I have written:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

e = Entry(root, width =35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 3, padx =10, pady=10)

# e.insert(0, "Enter Your Name: ")

def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.insert(0,str(current) + str(number)
    


#Define Buttons

button1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button2 = Button(root, text='2', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button3 = Button(root, text='3', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button4 = Button(root, text='4', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button5 = Button(root, text='5', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button6 = Button(root, text='6', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button7 = Button(root, text='7', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button8 = Button(root, text='8', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button9 = Button(root, text='9', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button0 = Button(root, text='0', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))

buttonadd = Button(root, text='+', padx=39, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click())
buttonequal = Button(root, text='=', padx=91, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click())
buttonclear = Button(root, text='C', padx=79, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click())
#Put the Buttons on the screen

button1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button9.grid(row=1, column=2)

button0.grid(row=4, column=0)

buttonclear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
buttonadd.grid(row=5, column=0)
buttonequal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)





root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line.  Please show us the line in context, with the lines before and after.  If you miss a close paren on the line before, for example, Python can't diagnose the problem until it sees the next line.

Comment: there seems to be no error, can You provide more code? specifically the `button_click` function and lines above 18 (17, 16, 15....) as well as line 18

Comment: You're potentially missing a `)` on the line above. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Just *command=button_click*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem; you're not closing the bracket.

`e.insert(0,str(current) + str(number)`

Comment: Oh I didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

missing a parentheses here:

```
e.insert(0,str(current) + str(number)
```

should be:

```
e.insert(0,str(current) + str(number))
```

Comment: Oh thats my bad. Thank you!

Comment: @Shrish You also have issues with inputing numbers, they somehow double up

Comment: Yea, I'm following a tutorial, so the tutor is about to fix that.